# Partial derivatives and Galilean transforms

Tags: coordinate-systems, derivatives, calculus

I have trouble understanding the following:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} = \frac {\partial x}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial t}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t'} = \frac {\partial x}{\partial t'} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial t}{\partial t'} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}
\end{equation}

given that $x = x' -vt$ and $t=t'$. I have a mental block in how the expression above are derived. Can someone give a dumb down explanation?

Answer (score 3):

Just apply the differential operators to an arbitrary function of $(t,x)$ computed at $t(t',x')$ and $x(t',x')$; then use chain differentiation:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t'}\,f(t(t',x'),x(t',x'))=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t(t',x'),x(t',x'))\,\frac{\partial t}{\partial t'}(t',x')+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t(t',x'),x(t',x'))\,\frac{\partial x}{\partial t'}(t',x')
$$

and similarly for $x'$. Since this is true of all functions $f$, the relations you wrote hold.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#General_rule) for derivatives.

Comment: Thank you - the link to chain rule helped. I think I was mixing up the chain rule with the product rule. And the choice of naming the variables added to the confusion.